# How to ignore single touch action before two fingers touch in android custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need scaling feature in my painting app, so I use ScaleGestureDetector, but when I perform two fingers touch action to zoom - before it triggers single touch action and draws something on Canvas, how can I check, that canvas is zooming now and ignore single touch action?

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    event.transform(touchMatrix)

    val x = event.x
    val y = event.y

    when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            presenter.onPlotClick(x, y)
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> {

        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            presenter.onFingerMoveOnPlot(x, y)
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {

        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            presenter.onFingerUpFromPlot()
        }
    }

    invalidate()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my mind, the problem is that both fingers aren't likely to touch the screen at the same time when performing a two-finger gesture. But you still want single-finger actions to be displayed right away, so you can't wait to render the single-finger action or else the user will perceive lag. So, what I might try is to render the single-finger action immediately, and then if a second finger is detected within a certain timeframe AND the first finger hasn't moved beyond a certain distance, you undo the single-finger action and instead interpret it as a two-finger action.